# How to update a date field in elm model

Tags: date, time, datepicker, elm

I'm making an interface that allows to pick a date and a time. So the first thing would be to store said date in a model field `date: Date`. Than I would have for example a DatePicker to select a year-month-day part. For hours and minutes I guess I need two input fields or select fields or counter fields or whatever with `onInput` event trigger.

The question is: how do I proceed on said event? How do I update my date in the model if only hour or minute number changed?

```elm
HourChange hour ->
    { model | date = ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer really depends on what kind of datepicker you need; there are many ways of implementing one.

Just as an example, here's how you could leverage the HTML5's datepicker and timepicker (Elm 0.18):

```elm
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (type_)
import Html.Events exposing (onInput)


main =
    Html.beginnerProgram
        { model = initialModel
        , view = view
        , update = update
        }


-- MODEL

type alias Model =
    { date : String
    , time : String
    }


initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    { date = ""
    , time = ""
    }


-- UPDATE

type Msg
    = ChangeDate String
    | ChangeTime String


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        ChangeDate newDate ->
            { model | date = newDate }

        ChangeTime newTime ->
            { model | time = newTime }


-- VIEW

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ input [ type_ "date", onInput ChangeDate ] []
        , input [ type_ "time", onInput ChangeTime ] []
        , text (toString model)
        ]
```

The thing is, this may or may not be what you want. For example you may want a smarter datepicker, or a better one in terms of usability. The example above just demonstrates one of the possible ways.

There are also Elm libraries that may help you achieve your needs. See for example [elm-datepicker](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Bogdanp/elm-datepicker/latest).

Comment: Using html5 controls is a good idea. But does it have a good way to get a value of elm Date type? Otherwise I have to somehow construct a query to send it to server.
UPDATE: Nevermind. I see that with Date type I would have to construct a query in some non-evident way anyway.

Comment: I ended up using this method since both datepicker and timepicker give a good way to construct a string to use `Date.fromString` on. You can even add a time zone selector to that.

Comment: This is awesome! Unfortunately looks like it's only supported in Chrome and Edge browsers. https://caniuse.com/#search=date

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options, but each of them will require constructing a new `Date` value by pulling each date part out of your current `model.date` value.

There is a package called [rluiten/elm-date-extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/rluiten/elm-date-extra/8.1.2/Date-Extra-Create#dateFromFields) which exposes a `dateFromFields` function that lets you specify each date part. Using this library, your code would look something like this:

```elm
import Date exposing (..)
import Date.Extra.Create exposing (dateFromFields)

...

HourChange hour ->
    { model | date =
        dateFromFields
               (year model.date)
               (month model.date)
               (day model.date)
               hour
               (minute model.date)
               (second model.date)
               (millisecond model.date)
    }
```

The core [`Date`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/Date) package currently supports creating dates from strings (or time) only. You could write the same sort of function as `dateFromFields` by concatenating together a string date, but it might be easier just to import that elm-date-extra package.

Comment: Maybe it is better to write it myself. Since this library doesn't permit to change time zone on the fly.

Comment: UPDATE: Nevermind :) I see that js doesn't have a good time zone manipulation tools.